# "Дети, рожденные матерями" или "дети, рожденные от матерей"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Тренируюсь в переводе текстов на русский ([Autism and DDT](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-018-05994-1)):

> Исследовательская команда Брауна не обнаружила корреляции между содержанием метаболитов ПХД и аутизмом. В то же время выяснилось, что у детей, **рожденных матерями**, чьи образцы попали в верхний квартиль по содержанию метаболитов ДДТ, риск развития аутизма был на 32% выше, чем у детей, **рожденных матерями** с более низким содержанием метаболитов ДДТ. Риск рождения ребенка с аутизмом, сопровождающимся умственной отсталостью, оказался вдвое выше у матерей с повышенными уровнями ДДТ по сравнению с матерями, чьи уровни ДДТ были ниже.

Задумался - можно ли написать "у детей, рожденных от матерей"? Или "рожденных матерями" правильно, а "от матерей" - нет?

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, если речь идет о происхождении детей, то уместно говорить "рожденные от матерей", хотя и "рожденные матерями" допустимо, а если проблемы возникли в процессе родов, то только "рожденные матерями".

Answer (score 0):

Не могу обнаружить какой-либо разницы между этими двумя вариантами в предложенном контексте. Более того, думаю, что в любом разумном контексте эти варианты взаимозаменяемы. Поиск в сети по (около)научной литературе подтверждает, как мне кажется, это предположение.